# Can anyone advise with header?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this project [https://alina12g.github.io/capstone-colmar/](http://alina12g.github.io/capstone-colmar/) and I can't understand why the header is "missing" even if it's fixed if I scroll to middle of the page. As well for mobile version I have a margin that make me scroll to the right. Can anyone advise please?
 **Thank you!**

Comment: I have one question. Did you design the website yourself or using some other template?

Comment: please don't share a url, show us some code, links can become invalid, change etc, these questions are static. Tell us more.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your CSS class ".desktop-header" in file:"/resources/css/style.css".
Add {z-index:100;}

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving the header **desktop-header** and **mobile-header** a `z-index:5`.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a z-index > 1

```
z-index: 9;
```

Comment: I fixed with body{
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
  }         Thank you very much!